# Iterate through a string backwards to find a character or phrase

Tags: c#, string, indexof

Is there a good way to start at a given index and move BACKWARDS looking for a given phrase in a string? I only know how to use indexof iterating forwards.

Comment: can you copy/paste your code and also what do u mean by move backwards

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  Most likely, from the wording of your question, you just want the answer that @Mark Byers gave below.  If not, however, we need a lot more detail please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx):

```
int index = s.LastIndexOf("foo");
```

It also has an optional start index if you want to start search backwards from somewhere other than the end of the string.

```
int index = s.LastIndexOf("foo", 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LastIndexOf http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx.